# object-fit: contain doesnt fit an A4 size div in a smaller element

Tags: html, css, scale, object-fit

I am trying to fit an A4 size div in a smaller element. I thought about using `object-fit: contain;` for this. When I read the doc on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), it seems perfect for my need. The auto-scale is sweet. I guess I forgot something somewhere.

[Try it online!](https://jsbin.com/honejobuxe/edit?html,css,output)

```css
header {
  background: orange;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
}

main {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: white;

}

.block {
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
}

.pdf {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 297mm;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>header</header>
  <div class="block">
    <aside>aside</aside>
    <main>
      <div class="pdf"></div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note I am not able to use grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesnt fit and it is a normal behavior.

> The `object-fit` CSS property specifies how the contents of a `replaced element`, such as an `<img>` or `<video>`, should be resized to fit its container.

Your div is not a replaced elements.

> Typical replaced elements are:
>
> ```
> <iframe>
> <video>
> <embed>
> <img>
> ```
>
> Some elements are treated as replaced elements only in specific cases:
>
> ```
> <option>
> <audio>
> <canvas>
> <object>
> <applet>
> ```

source:

- [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)
- [Replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)